# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes and restarts when opening LibreOFFICE

Tags: shutdown, libreoffice, crash, restart

Upon opening LIbre office ,, my system shuts down and restarts into the login page . i cant open libre office because of this . I had recently updated all the softwares in Ubuntu . The version installed is Ubuntu 14.04 .